# "EOF in header" => POI

Tags: c#, apache-poi, npoi, sharpziplib

Iam trying to pass in a `MemoryStream`(not a `Filestream`).

This is what I did:

```
        XWPFDocument w2 = new XWPFDocument(memoryStream);
```

This is what I get:

> EOF in header

**Updated my post:**

```
        var m_a = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path_docx));

        // this works:
        //byte[] tempDatei = m_a.ToArray();
        //XWPFDocument m_w1 = new XWPFDocument(new MemoryStream(tempDatei)); 

        XWPFDocument m_w1 = new XWPFDocument(m_a);
        //  ... do something with the document
        m_w1.Write(m_a);

        // Actually, I want to use the same MemoryStream
        XWPFDocument m_w2 = new XWPFDocument(m_a);
        m_a.Position = 0;
        //  ... do something with the document
        m_w2.Write(m_a);

        // Dispose later
        if (m_a != null)
        {
            m_a.Close();
            m_a.Dispose();
        }
```

The main goal is to use the same MemoryStream, dispose later

Comment: Is the memory stream empty?  It seems to be attempting to read pdf info and if the stream is empty it cannot even read the header to determine if it is a pdf.

Comment: Can you show us how you are creating/populating the MemoryStream?  A [mre] would help us help you.